# How to change Qt applications's dock icon at run-time in MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, dock

I need to change my Qt application's dock icon (in MacOS X) in run-time according to some conditions.

I've found several recipes on [trolltech.com](http://trolltech.com):

1. `QApplication::setIcon()`
2. `setApplicationIcon()`
3. `qt_mac_set_app_icon()`

but none of it works: there is no such methods/functions in Qt 4.5.

How can I change my application's dock icon and what icon formats can I use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Qt 4.5 the methods you are searching for are called

```
QApplication::setWindowIcon(const QIcon &)
```

or

```
QWidget::setWindowIcon(const QIcon &).
```

You can use every image format for icons that Qt supports (e.g. BMP, GIF, JPG, PNG, TIFF, XPM, ...).

Maybe you want to have a look at Qt's documentation at http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/index.html or use the Qt Assistant.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: You're right. I was confused with the phrase "default window icon" in documentation. Thanks!